# Save file with any language using unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, reportlab

I'm creating a simple script that takes a list of images as an input and outputs a pdf file, using the [Reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/) pdf-generation module. The script takes the filename as shown above:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
filename = raw_input("Enter pdf filename: ")
c = canvas.Canvas(filename + ".pdf")
c.save()
```

Everything is awesome, until the user input non-english filename (Hebrew, Arabic), which cause the code to throw the following exception:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

So, I decided to use unicode instead, but when I use `unicode()` it throws me another exception:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

However, when I decode the string encoding it works like a charm (Hebrew example):

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
filename = raw_input("Enter pdf filename: ")
filename = filename.decode("windows-1255")
c = canvas.Canvas(filename + ".pdf")
c.save()
```

I continued to try another methods, and found that if I write before the string `u` like in the example above, it works in **any** language:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
filename = u"أ" #arabic
c = canvas.Canvas(filename + ".pdf")
c.save()
```

The problem is that I **dont know** what encoding I should use. The input string could be in any language. What can I do to fix it, or in other words: How can I add `u` before string without speicfy the encoding?

*PS: If you have better title, please write me down below*

**Edit:** The filename is actually provided from a website (I use `urllib`). I didnt thought it matters and I used `raw_input()` to make the problem more clear. Sorry for that

Comment: @matsjoyce: no, it does not. `u''` uses the *source code encoding* to determine how to interpret your literal string loaded from a file.

Comment: Are you using Windows or a different platform?

Comment: And what value are you looking to decode, the `raw_input()` string?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Im using windows, and I want to decode the `raw_input()` string.

Comment: Then my answer below applies.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the filename is actually provided from a website (I use urllib). I didnt thought it matters and I used raw_input() to make the problem more clear. So I'm not sure your answer is relevant. I'll check it out once Ill be back at home (Writing from my android). Thanks!

Comment: How are you parsing the response? Is it HTML? Does the server provide a `charset` parameter in the `Content-Type` header? You'll need to detect the characterset from the context provided, but you'll need to update your question to reflect your actual source of the filename if you want a more applicable answer. When using `raw_input()` the context is `sys.stdin`, when reading from a URL, the context in totally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got the solution! Once I got the text from the server I parsed it using [BeutifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (Thank you @Martijn Pieters!), that has charset detection library:

```
resp = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com").read() 
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp)
string = soup.find_all("span")[0].text
```

And then I just used `string` as the file name:

```
c = canvas.Canvas(path + "/" + string + ".pdf")
```

The full credit goes to @Martijn Pieters that recommended me to use BS.
This is not the first script HTML parsing script I wrote, and I always used regex. I highly recommend anyone to use BeautifulSoup instead, trust me it's much better then regex.

Answer (score 5):

`raw_input()` strings are encoded by the terminal or console, so you'd ask the terminal or console for the right codec to use.

Python has already done this at startup time, and stored the codec in `sys.stdin.encoding`:

```
import sys

filename = raw_input("Enter pdf filename: ")
filename = filename.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
```

From the comments you indicated that the filename is not actually sourced from `raw_input()`. For different sources, you'll need to use different techniques to detect the character set used.

For example, HTTP responses *may* include a `charset` parameter in the `Content-Type` header; a `urllib` or `urllib2` response lets you extract that with:

```
encoding = response.info().getparam('charset')
```

This can still return `None`, at which point it depends on the exact mimetype returned. The default for `text/` mimetypes (such as HTML) is Latin-1, but the HTML standard also allows for `<meta>` headers in the document itself to tell you the characterset used. For HTML, I'd use BeautifulSoup to parse the response, it'll detect the characterset for you.

Without more information on how you *actually* load the filename from a URL, however, I cannot say anything more specific.

Comment: Thank you! I'm now adding more info

Comment: **More Info:** The server actually return charset, however it always return `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`, and decoding it using `utf-8` doesn't work. To be more specific- the tool I develop send POST request to search in a website, then it parse it using regular expressions and then it let the user select one of the results. After this, it create the PDF, that should have the name of the serach result the user selected. If using BeautifulSoup will solve this, ill do it, but I prefer regex. Anyway, I'll continue to try different methods and update here if I'd found something. Thx!

Comment: @ohad987: if decoding from UTF-8 doesn't work, then the server lied about the character set. Check the HTML response for `<meta>` tags then.

Comment: @ohad987: BeautifulSoup would detect that header for you, and probably give you better tools to extract the information you are looking for.

Comment: There is not info about encoding in the meta tags. Ill try `BeautifulSoup` now. Thanks again

Comment: @ohad987: BeautifulSoup falls back to using a character set detection library.

Comment: Thank you so much! Today I got some spare time to learn BS and it's  really great, and also works great with another lanugages. Maybe the server didn't lied and UTF-* is acutally the right encoding, but it doesn't natter now. Thanks again!